# mini attribute in jqm for toolbar look

Tags: jquery-mobile, button

I want to place some buttons in the top of my webapp that works like a toolbar. For this purpose I use the controlgroup widget.
Now I have the problem that the button widths are too big for the display so I decide to set the mini attribute to true.
But can anybody explain me the difference between setting mini to every button or only set it to the div? Which scenario should I use for my toolbar?

Example 1:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Button 1</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Button 2</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Button 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Button 1</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Button 2</a>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Button 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same because the buttons inherit from the container.  You should just set mini on the DIV in this situation.

If you had many controls in one container and only some needed to be "mini" you would then set those individual elements to mini.